# File `mparhack.sty' not found

Tags: packages

When I want to compile my tex file it throws this:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mparhack.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.131 \RequirePackage
                     {fixltx2e} % fixes some LaTeX stuff^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on tesis.log.
```

I do not know where should I get this missing file (`mparhack.sty`).

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I suggest you install vanilla texlive instead of the texlive from the package respiratory. The latter is badly old and also you don't know what to install to get the required package. I am also using ubuntu 12.04 and did this.

Comment: sounds to me like you're either using an version- don't use the version from the repositories, see [how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu); `mparhack` is installed by default

Answer (score 1):

The [Comprehensive TeX archive network](http://www.ctan.org) is the place to go. The package you need is [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mparhack).